# Class object unique_ptr reset, order of destruction / construction

Tags: c++, boost, constructor, destructor, unique-ptr

I have a vector of `unique_ptr` for an `ethernet_socket` class.  If I reset the pointer, I am seeing the constructor called first in my logs before the destructor.  Is this right, or is my boost logging lagging?

**pseudo code**

```
std::vector <boost::movelib::unique_ptr<eth_socket> > _eth_socket_vect;
_eth_socket_vect.resize(1);
_eth_socket_vect.at(0).reset(new eth_socket(host, port, delimiter, timeout, 1));     
// destructor is not called on first reset

// do some operations, then reset

_eth_socket_vect.at(0).reset(new eth_socket(host, port, delimiter, timeout, 1));

// do some more operations on new object
```

**logs for second reset being called**

```
20-02-28 08:44:14.312702 [info] src/eth_socket.cpp(eth_socket:10) >> started; host_num = 1  <---CONSTRUCTOR
20-02-28 08:44:14.312825 [info] src/eth_socket.cpp(open_eth_socket:67) >> started; host_num = 0
20-02-28 08:44:14.312869 [info] src/eth_socket.cpp(open_eth_socket:71) >> socket_host = 10.0.0.4; socket_port = 1337; host_num = 0
20-02-28 08:44:14.313016 [info] src/eth_socket.cpp(open_eth_socket:104) >> ended; host_num = 0
20-02-28 08:44:14.313054 [info] src/eth_socket.cpp(read_data:247) >> started; host_num = 0
20-02-28 08:44:14.313089 [info] src/eth_socket.cpp(read_data:275) >> ended; host_num = 0
20-02-28 08:44:14.313109 [info] src/eth_socket.cpp(eth_socket:38) >> ended; host_num = 1
20-02-28 08:44:14.313132 [info] src/eth_socket.cpp(~eth_socket:43) >> started; host_num = 0  <-- DESTRUCTOR
20-02-28 08:44:14.313225 [info] src/eth_socket.cpp(close_eth_socket:113) >> started; host_num = 0
20-02-28 08:44:14.313287 [info] src/eth_socket.cpp(socket_read_data_callback:368) >> started; host_num = 0
20-02-28 08:44:14.313299 [info] src/eth_socket.cpp(close_eth_socket:144) >> ended; host_num = 0
20-02-28 08:44:14.313327 [info] src/eth_socket.cpp(~eth_socket:58) >> ended; host_num = 0
```

Comment: The first `reset` does not free an `eth_socket`. The `vector` contains an "empty" `unique_ptr` after `resize(1)`

Comment: At first you create new socket object, then replace pointer with it, at this moment previous socket destroying.

Comment: man this should be obvious. Argument has to be evaluated first before method can be called so  `new eth_socket` must complete before `reset` is called which can release old object.

Comment: @MarekR oh I see, the new class object is created, then the original is destroyed and replaced by the new, thus the constructor is called before the destructor, relatively speaking

Comment: Are you using pre-C++11?

Comment: @walnut I am using C++11, but I could use 17

Comment: @xinthose Then why are you using `boost::movelib::unique_ptr` instead of `std::unique_ptr`?

Comment: @walnut because I use boost for everything else in the program, keeping it consistent

Comment: @xinthose I'm pretty sure you use a lot from the standard library too, so you could argue that when there's an overlap between boost and the standard, use the standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you resize the `vector`, its elements contain empty `unique_ptr` (equivalent to `nullptr`):

```
std::vector <boost::movelib::unique_ptr<eth_socket> > _eth_socket_vect;
_eth_socket_vect.resize(1);
```

Now you create an instance of `eth_socket`, so its constructor is invoked:

```
_eth_socket_vect.at(0).reset(new eth_socket(host, port, delimiter, timeout, 1));
```

Then you create another instance and replace the previous one. So, first `eth_socket` constructor is invoked, and then the destructor of the previous instance is called:

```
_eth_socket_vect.at(0).reset(new eth_socket(host, port, delimiter, timeout, 1));
```

Comment: don't you mean **second** `eth_socket` constructor is invoked, and then the destructor of the previous instance is called?

Comment: @xinthose It's _first_ as in the order of events. Not _**the** first `eth_socket` constructor ..._.